# Reading .txt files with PHP and store information into variables

Tags: php, text

I have a two `.txt` files that I need to read.
The content of the two files is below

> log.txt

```
2013/04/20 01:08:11
```

and

> data.txt

```
MANUFACTURER: SISYSTEM
MODELNAME: DX1
BIRTHDATE: 19710108
SEX: M
```

For log.txt i need to store the date from the first line and save it into mySQL database.

For data.txt i need to store information from each line into variables. i.e:

```
$manufacturer = SISYSTEM;
$modelname = DX1;
$birthdate =  19710108;
$sex = M;
```

For log.txt i can simply just read the first line using fget and store into one variable. However, for data.text, I am having trouble figuring out how to store multiple variables inside the loop. Here's what I have so far, but I don't know how to assign the values into new variables each time it goes through the while loop. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

   $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
   $parts = explode(':', trim($line_of_text) );


}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Comment: use the csv file functions [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: `$parts[] = explode(...)`. then $parts will be an array of the name/value pairs.

Comment: Why on earth do you want put it all into separate variables? You'll have no idea what was actually fetched later...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need them in variables? An associative array ("map") is the cleaner approach

```
$result = array();
  // Your loop -->
  $parts = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line_of_text, 2)));
  $result[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
```

Comment: Just add logic to reset the array when the script getsntomthe next set of data, assuming there is more than one set.

Comment: @Robert I hope I get you right (looks like you wrote from a smartphone?) I think the "there is more than one record in this file" is out of scope of this question, because we additional need to know, how the different records are separated from each other. And the "variable variable"-approach would suffer from the same problem anyway :) However, the first line already mentions how to reset the resulting structure: `$result=array()`

Comment: @KingCrunch Could you briefly explain how each line works? esp the array_map? How would I call these variables to store inside SQL database?

Comment: @alchuang Some basic understanding about PHP is probably useful... `$result` is an associative array at the end, thus you retrieve the values like usual: `$result['MODELNAME']`.

Answer (score 3):

Use variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Use in your while loop:

```
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode(':', trim($line_of_text), 2);
${strtolower($parts[0])} = trim($parts[1]);
```

Comment: data.txt: file_handle: oops!

Much better to check for 'MANUFACTURER' etc.

Comment: @τεκ changed. (limit to explode)

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `while` loop you can compare the line to see what variable you have to assign: [PHP: strcmp - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  $parts = explode(':', trim($line_of_text) );
  if (strcmp($parts[0], "MANUFACTURER")==0)
      $MANUFACTURER = trim($parts[1]);
  if (strcmp($parts[0], "MODELNAME")==0)
     $MODELNAME = trim($parts[1]);
  [...]
  else
     echo "I haven't recognised that: ".$parts[0];
}

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Probably you could use a `switch` statement

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  $parts = explode(':', trim($line_of_text) );
  switch($parts[0])
  case 'MANUFACTUREER':
      $manufactureer = $parts[1];
      break;
  case 'MODELNAME':
      $modelname = $parts[1];
      break;
  [...]
}

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: I don't know how to assign the values into new variables

You can use [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

I assume that you've just provided an example of what's in each file - that these patterns may repeat. Before I answer your question, I think it's important you should know that maintaining data in text files is a *very* bad idea or lots of reasons.

Taking the second file as an example, you've got 2 choices of how you manage this data in PHP - consider your data as a table:

```
manufctr  model   birthdate   sex
SISYSTEM  DX1     19710108    M
SISYSTEM  DX2     19710305    F
...
```

You could either store each row in an array, or each column in an array. And the resulting set of arrays can itself be stored in an array.

How you load and parse the data depends on how consistent the data structure will be (will each entry always be this format, or might it have extra / missing attributes). Whether you read the data into rows or columns depends on how the data is stored in the file and also what you intend doing next with the data.

```
$read=array();
while (true) {
   $record=array();
   for($x=0; $x<4; $x++) {
      $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
      list($k, $v) = explode(':', $line_of_text );
      $record[strtolower(trim($k))]=trim($v);
   }
   $read[]=$record;
   if (feof($file_handle) break;
}
```